# How to get the name of the tracked image in Swift with RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have multiple AR Reference images and I want to know which one I am currently tracking. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else {
      print("No images available")
      return
  }
    
  configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
  configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
  sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)` method. When your app detects an image it recognizes it will add an anchor. You can pull the name of that image from your asset catalogue.

Add this to your `ARSCNViewDelegate` class:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let image = imageAnchor.referenceImage
    // this is one means of getting the name of the image
    if let trackedImage = image.name {
        print(trackedImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need RealityKit's solution, not SceneKit's one, use the following code:

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        guard let imageAnchor = anchors.first as? ARImageAnchor,
              let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else { return }

        print(name)
        
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)
        
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Don't forget implement session delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arView.session.delegate = self
    }
}
```